# How to play mp3 files from the command line?

Tags: sound, music-player

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 server.. so command line only.

I need to be able to play audio (.mp3 & .wav) files via the command line!

I've installed the MPD & Audacious packages... and copied some files to a location specified in the .conf file.

But what do I do to acutally play the .mp3 files??

Also, how can I confirm the AUDIO is working correctly?

Comment: You want to play it from the 'server' speakers or you want to play it across the network?  Two very different things.

Comment: Audio through jack output, not over network (initially).

Comment: You could try installing sox, then at the commandline it would be  "play thisorthat.mp3" or "play ~/music/thisfolder/thisorthat.mp3"

Answer (score 85):

If you already have ffmpeg installed (you should have ffmpeg installed default with ubuntu), try:

```
ffplay example.mp3
```

or (without text output, window opening and looping):

```
ffplay -v 0 -nodisp -autoexit example.mp3
```

or reading from stdin, piped from a command:

```
cat example.mp3 | ffplay -v 0 -nodisp -autoexit -
```

Comment: While it does play, it also opens up a GUI window.

Comment: -nodisp option makes it not open a GUI window.

Comment: it seems to keep running after it finishes playing the audio.

Comment: On my system at least `ffplay -loop 9999 sound.wav` also seamlessly loops the audio.

Comment: This is the one I use `ffplay -nodisp -autoexit sound.ogg >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: You can also use `ffplay -v warning -nodisp -autoexit sound.ogg` as an alternative to still see warnings

Answer (score 74):

For wav you can use `aplay`.  For mp3 you can use `mpg123`.

Comment: Perfect, works great with `sudo pip install gTTS` (Google Text to Speech/https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS) then `gtts-cli "The good of mankind far outweighs the bad" | mpg123 -`.

Comment: mpg321 is a good option.

Answer (score 18):

I usually just do `mplayer foo.mp3` to play audio from the command line.

Comment: `mplayer --vo=null musicClip.mp4` disables the video if you want just the music.

Answer (score 15):

The `play` command from the `sox` package will play any file format supported by `sox`

To install `sox` open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
```

To use `play` command:

```
play file_name.extension
```

Use `man sox` for more information

<sub>reference [here](https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-play-music-from-command-line-terminal/)</sub>

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if your server will support it, but VLC also has a command line version that can play (with the right packages) MP3 files:

```
nvlc file.mp3
```

The 'n' in front of 'vlc' invokes the ncurses interface which is for the command line. This allows you to play multiple files, pause and control the files being played.

And additionally you can use 
`nvlc --random /path/to/your/music/folder` 
to play random songs from a Music folder.

Or use `cvlc` instead of `nvlc`, for even minimal interaction.

Answer (score 8):

You can test the sound quite simply: `speaker-test -c6` (where `-c6` indicates I want to test 6 channels for a 5.1 setup)

But for playing music, `mpd` is just a server.

It needs a frontend to tell it to do things. Check out `mpc` for a fairly basic command line player. There are of course [many, many clients](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Clients) (including graphical ones you can connect over the network) so you can play around with those.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the speaker-test.... worked great.  I'll also check out mpc.

Answer (score 5):

ffplay has -loglevel quiet, so no need to redirect output to the platform-specific /dev/null. So, building on others' answers,

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -loglevel quiet filename.{wav,mp3,ogg,...}
```

Try `ffplay -formats`, see https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html.

Answer (score 2):

You told you have audacious installed. You can play audio file in command line by `audacious -Hq file`.

Comment: actually it should be `-Hq`, not `-hq`... but yes. And omg why is this not the accepted answer??

Answer (score 2):

[**mpv**](https://mpv.io/) is a descendant of mplayer, which [mlevin](https://askubuntu.com/a/115400/567307) mentions. Many of the old command line switches still work, but some of the keyboard shortcuts have changed.

It also has the ability to "play" folders (by queuing all media files contained within).

```
mpv --vo=null -shuffle .
```

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered this terminal dedicated music player:

Install package "moc"
and launch `mocp` for a cool visual terminal music player (with no risk of making pop-ups of cover art, etc, like `mplayer1 does)

Comment: Great option, _when it works_. I get it to work on my main machine, but not on the machine with the music collection from which I want it to work :| ... `aplay` plays wav files fine, but mocp claims it cannot open the ALSA device ... neither can cmus. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Using smplayer to play audio .m4a files

```
cd ~/Music/Songs_m4a
smplayer .
```

This is SMPlayer v. 0.8.6 running on Linux.

**NOTE**: No interface displayed. It just play all the audio files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If someone finds this answer looking how to play audio in a script, we ended up using a Python package called `playsound`:

https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound

Playsound is implemented in pure Python and works in almost any Linux, OSx and Windows. No external command required. At it supports MP3 and HTTPS URIs too!

How to use it?

```
sudo pip3 install playsound
python3 -c 'from playsound import playsound; playsound("https://your.domain/sound.mp3")'
```

Or, again, if scripting or coding in Python, incorporate it in your code.