# How to add a custom alert sound in Unity

Tags: external-soundcard, sound-theme

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. How to add custom alert sound in Ubuntu Unity ?

**Note**: my question is not `how to play music via terminal`. I can use `play` command from **sox** package.

Also not [make-a-sound-once-process-is-complete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/make-a-sound-once-process-is-complete)

For better clarity this link may be useful   [add-your-custom-alert-sound-for.html](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/09/gnome-add-your-custom-alert-sound-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use `aplay /path/to/file` as notification when a command is done with `command && aplay /path/to/file`, but there are multiple other options to do so. Check out these

- https://superuser.com/q/276596/418028
- https://askubuntu.com/a/316048/295286
- http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-play-music-from-command-line-terminal/

Comment: I append `&& mplayer -really-quiet`.