# How do I set battery full alert tone in ubuntu 18.04 to save battery wear out?

Tags: battery, charging

My battery has gone faulty for the third time now. Now I want to set an alarm when my battery charge reaches 90%, so that I can disconnect it.

Can someone help me in setting that up?

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-do-i-check-the-batterys-status-via-the-terminal may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the best way, but you can do something like the following.

1. First you'll need `acpi`. Install it by running

   ```
   sudo apt install acpi
   ```
2. Next you need to create a bash script. Create an empty text file, say `battery-full.sh` and add the following lines

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while true
       do
           export DISPLAY=:0.0
           battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
           if on_ac_power; then                                #check if AC is plugged in
               if [ $battery_level -ge 90 ]; then              #check if the battery level is over 90%
                   notify-send -u critical "Please unplug your AC adapter" "Battery level: ${battery_level}% (charged above 90%)" -i battery-full-charged
                fi
           fi
         sleep 300                                             #wait for 300 seconds before checking again

       done
   ```
3. [Make the script executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/286621/480481) and run it. You'll get a persistent notification if the battery is charging and the level is over 90%.

You can also get a sound alert by adding a suitable a audio-playing command after the `notify-send` command in the script above. For example you can you the `play` command from the `sox` package (for other options, [see this](https://askubuntu.com/q/115369/480481)). First install it by running

```
sudo apt install sox
```

Then modify the `notify-send` line in the script as follows

```
notify-send -u critical "Please unplug your AC adapter" "Battery level: ${battery_level}% (charged above 90%)" -i battery-full-charged; play /path/to/audio-file
```

(Replace `/path/to/audio-file` by a valid path to an actual audio file present in your system).

You may also consider [adding the script to your startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/480481) so that it starts automatically every time you boot your laptop.

Comment: can I get an alert tone using this?

Comment: @Kethan Yes, you can append a proper audio-playing command after the `notify-send` command in the script. Please see the update to the answer (after point 3).

Comment: Cool script I read similar ones just a few minutes ago. The neatest one though is where the charger is plugged into a WiFi controlled wall outlet pass through switch that disconnected/reconnected power to the charger power brick. Only problem is I never use my laptop on battery and I want to buy a new laptop every 2 years on average. So for me it's a mute point if the battery lasts 5 years or 10 years :/

Comment: @pomsky thank you so much, worked perfectly

Answer (score 6):

I don't like to install extra programs and utilities on my laptop, so I am thinking about a solution without `acpi`. Inspired by @pomsky's response, the below scripts may be a better solution.

Update: It does detect if the battery is already fully charged thanks to @mdebusk and @blaze-fire(krishan singh)

For Gnome:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while true
    do 
        export DISPLAY=:0.0
        battery_level=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`
        battery_status=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`
        if [ $battery_status = "Charging" ] && [ $battery_level -ge 85 ];
        then
            notify-send -u critical "Battery fully charged"
        fi
        sleep 120
    done
```

For KDE:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while true
    do 
        export DISPLAY=:0.0
        battery_level=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`
        battery_status=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`
        if [ $battery_status = "Charging" ] && [ $battery_level -ge 85 ];
        then
            kdialog --msgbox "Battery fully charged" 5
        fi
        sleep 120
    done
```

as you can see, the only difference is in the notification systems of KDE and Gnome . We use `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/` facilities instead of `acpi`. make the script executable: `chmod +x SCRIPTNAME.sh`, then add it to startup.

hope this help.

Comment: +1 It's clean and simple which I like!

Comment: its clean and simple , what is the purpose of 
this line export DISPLAY=:0.0

Comment: @saravana [linuxquestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/export-display%3D-0-0-a-682926/)

Comment: It doesn't detect if the battery is already full charged. In my case, I can handle it by checking if battery_status is "Unknown".

Comment: @nafiur-rahman-khadem I already know about that, but to be honest, I'm not a bash programmer, so it would be great if you could [fix it](https://gist.github.com/reganto/addd1853ffc0dcf0d3944cd068c37ed7#file-battery_full_alarm-sh).

Comment: @Reganto [This](https://gist.github.com/reganto/addd1853ffc0dcf0d3944cd068c37ed7?permalink_comment_id=4217829#gistcomment-4217829) seems to work on my system.

Comment: Thanks @MDeBusk, It works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the battery charge limiter to say 60% to 80% if you aren't planning on taking it on the road. However for my laptop at least I can only change it in Windows as this answer details:

- [Re: Plugged in, charging but won't pass 70%](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Plugged-in-charging-but-won-t-pass-70/td-p/4211919)

> The reason why your battery would stay upto 70% and not charge further
>   could be due to an option called "Desktop Mode" which might be
>   enabled. Desktop mode helps in disabling the battery to charge upto
>   100% to maximize the life of the battery. This option can also be
>   disabled. To disable this option:
>
> - Right-click the battery icon on the Windows notification area, and then click Dell Extended Battery life Options
> - The Battery Meter dialog box is displayed, Click the Desktop Mode tab
> - Select the option to disable this feature
> - Then, click OK

I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 so it's not a big deal to change the battery charge limiter. I don't know of any apps to do this in Linux. It would be a nifty little C program to write for my inaugural journey into the Linux Kernel coding though.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [@pornsky](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157614/1581732)'s answer,  the format of the acpi output wasn't working with @pornsky's code, so I modified it a little bit. The following script got the job done for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
    do
        on_ac=`acpi | grep -o 'Charging'`
        battery_level=`acpi -b| grep -P -o '\d+(?=%)'| sed -n 2p`
        if [[ "$on_ac" == "Charging" ]]; then                                #check if AC is plugged in
            if [ $battery_level -ge 90 ]; then              #check if the battery level is over 90%
                notify-send -u critical "Please unplug your AC adapter" "Battery level: ${battery_level}% (charged above 90%)" -i battery-full-charged
             fi
        fi
      sleep 300                                             #wait for 300 seconds before checking again

    done
```

Check out his answer for more depth

Comment: Not a good answer when you are needing to reference other information that may not be there later. If you need info from that answer to make your answer work you need to include it in your answer not just a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@Regantos](https://askubuntu.com/a/1358853/1595037) answer for KDE:

- Fixing small syntax errors like missing space in line 9 and removing
  redundant nested if statements.
- Now make script executable using `sudo chmod +x /path-to-script/`
- Add script as login script in background
  services in kubuntu which makes it run automatically after you login

While copying script beware of the intended spaces as they will affect the output.

**Note:** In order to play audio you will have to install [Sox](https://ubunlog.com/en/sox-reproduce-mp3-terminal/)

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
    do 
        export DISPLAY=:0.0
        battery_level=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity`
        battery_status=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status`
        if [ $battery_status = "Charging" ] && [ $battery_level -ge 85 ];
        then
                play /path-to-mp3-file;  // to play alert sound
                kdialog --msgbox "Battery fully charged";
        fi
        sleep 120       // cooldown time
    done
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234417)