# Play a mp3 file using python

Tags: sound, python3, playonlinux, mp3

I have this code called CountDown Program. What my program does is:

1. Count down from 60.
2. Play a sound file (`alarm.wav`) when the countdown reaches zero. This means the code needs to do the following:

   - Pause for one second in between displaying each number in the countdown by calling `time.sleep()`.
   - Call `subprocess.Popen()` to open the sound file with the default application.

Here's the code for it:

```py
import time , subprocess,os
from subprocess import call

def countDown():
    for i in range (10):
        print(i, end='')
        time.sleep(1)

countDown()
subprocess.call([ 'bomb.mp3'])
```

When I run this I get:

```
Error: File not Found
```

I tried with:

```py
subprocess.call([ 'home/username/bomb.mp3']) # location specified
```

But I got:

```
Error: Permission denied
```

Then, I tried with `Popen`:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'bomb.mp3'], shell=True)
```

But I got:

```
Error: 0123456789bomb.mp3: 1: start: not found
```

I am not quite sure why this code does not work on Ubuntu, because it works fine on Windows.

What I can do for this? Is there any method to open mp3 files using Python on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or am I missing out any argument?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To identify how to start a shell program, first try to do is in terminal. Once OK, put the right command in your python program.  Maybe this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115369/how-to-play-mp3-files-from-the-command-line) will try and help you identify the correct way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```py
subprocess.call(['xdg-open', '/home/username/bomb.mp3'])
```

`bomb.mp3` (or `alarm.wav`) is not a program or script you want to run, but a file you want to open. As your goal appears to be to open it in whatever graphical application is currently registered to handle it--which is what at least one of the earlier versions of your script did when run in Windows--you should use the [`xdg-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) command.

Besides using `xdg-open`, I've also added a leading `/` to the front of the path, without which it is resolved relative to the current directory (which would presumably fail except when the current directory is `/`).

---

The first version of your program, or something similar to it, may have worked on Windows because, on Windows, non-executable files can be run as commands. This causes them to be open with whatever program their file type is associated with. Most operating systems *and most shells* do not behave this way. Windows also provides a command for doing this (with slightly different semantics) called `start`. But other operating systems, such as Ubuntu, don't have `start`. So when you tried that on Ubuntu, it didn't work either.

What Ubuntu has is `xdg-open`. Ubuntu is not alone here--`xdg-open` doesn't work in Windows or macOS, but it does work on systems with graphical desktop environments that follow the [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) standards. This includes just about any GNU/Linux system (and some other Unix-like operating systems) *if the user has a graphical desktop environment installed*.

For the `xdg-open` command to actually *succeed*, the user must be logged in to a graphical session.

(On macOS, you'd use `open`.)